# What is the best practice to deploy single instance with http access on GCP

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, cloud

What is the best practice to deploy a single instance with HTTP access on GCP?
I want to deploy an app on a single GCP instance that doesn't need to be scalable, and only needs to have HTTP access, so what is the best practice to do such deployment?

1. add the instance to the instance group and direct the traffic through LB
2. add the instance with a public IP address & check the "Allow HTTP access" while creating the instance

Or is there another best practice for such case?